# Does OutputStream.write(buf, offset, size) have memory leak on Linux?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, outputstream

I write a piece of java code to create 500K small files (average 40K each) on CentOS. The original code is like this:

```
 package MyTest;

 import java.io.*;

 public class SimpleWriter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dir = args[0];
    int fileCount = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    String content="@#$% SDBSDGSDF ASGSDFFSAGDHFSDSAWE^@$^HNFSGQW%#@&$%^J#%@#^$#UHRGSDSDNDFE$T#@$UERDFASGWQR!@%!@^$#@YEGEQW%!@%!!GSDHWET!^";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 40 * 1024 / content.length();
    int remainder = (40 * 1024) % content.length();
    for (int i=0; i < count; i++)
    {
        sb.append(content);
    }
    if (remainder > 0)
    {
        sb.append(content.substring(0, remainder));
    }

    byte[] buf = sb.toString().getBytes();

    for (int j=0; j < fileCount; j++)
    {
        String path = String.format("%s%sTestFile_%d.txt", dir, File.separator, j);
        try{
            BufferedOutputStream fs = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
            fs.write(buf);
            fs.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fe)
        {
            System.out.printf("Hit filenot found exception %s", fe.getMessage());
        }
        catch(IOException ie)
        {
            System.out.printf("Hit IO exception %s", ie.getMessage());

        }

    }
}

  }
```

You can run this by issue following command:
  java -jar SimpleWriter.jar my_test_dir 500000

I thought this is a simple code, but then I realize that this code is using up to 14G of memory.  I know that because when I use free -m to check the memory, the free memory kept dropping, until my 15G memory VM only had 70 MB free memory left.  I compiled this using Eclipse, and I compile this against JDK 1.6 and then JDK1.7. The result is  the same.  The funny thing is that, if I comment out fs.write(), just open and close the stream, the memory stabilized at certain point.  Once I put fs.write() back, the memory allocation just go wild.  500K 40KB files is about 20G.  It seems Java's stream writer never deallocate its buffer during the operation.

I once thought java GC does not have time to clean.  But this make no sense since I closed the file stream for every file.  I even transfer my code into C#, and running under windows, the same code producing 500K 40KB files with memory stable at certain point, not taking 14G as under CentOS.  At least C#'s behavior is what I expected, but I could not believe Java perform this way.  I asked my colleague who were experienced in java.  They could not see anything wrong in code, but could not explain why this happened.  And they admit nobody had tried to create 500K file in a loop without stop.

I also searched online and everybody says that the only thing need to pay attention to, is close the stream, which I did.

Can anyone help me to figure out what's wrong?

Can anybody also try this and tell me what you see?

BTW, some people in this community tried the code on Windows and it seemed to worked fine.  I didn't tried it on windows.  I only tried in Linux as I thought that where people use Java for.  So, it seems this issue happened on Linux).

I also did the following to limit the JVM heap, but it take no effects
    java -Xmx2048m -jar SimpleWriter.jar my_test_dir 500000

Comment: "The code is like this" - do you mean you wrote up something that resembles your code and posted that, or is this a snippet from your actual code? If this isn't your actual code, does running this cause 14 GB of memory consumption?

Comment: Bizarre. You wouldn't happen to be reading these files later, would you?

Comment: Is this an in-memory file system?

Comment: No, I just try to write to local disk, or any mounted NFS folders (EBS in AWS, or shared NFS folder on another machine).  Regardless destination, the memory issue remains.

Comment: Does the problem show up if you run this code on Windows?

Comment: In Windows the example with 40K size - 500K files (as shown by visualVM): Heap used: 4M, Heap size: 16M and memory used from OS point of view: 16M. The example with 40Mb size - 500 files Heap used: 250M Heap size: 340M (also the OS sees 340M allocated memory)

Comment: BufferedOutputStream is only useful if you are buffering multiple small writes into larger writes.  In this case you can drop it as you only have one write.

Comment: I changed my program to use FileOutputStream and the behavior is the same under Linux. I actually tried it under CentOS and RedHat, Aamzon Linux.  All the same.  It is the Linux environment that I need to have this fixed.

Comment: How are you measuring the amount of memory used? Do you mean the amount used by just your 1 JVM? Or do you mean the total used by the system as a whole?

Comment: Are you saying that -Xmx is ignored by your JVM? Can you please post a screenshot from Visual VM (inside your `JAVA_HOME/bin` folder) while the test is running? Also please make the following changes in your code: remove `StringBuilder` just make your `byte[]` hard-coded like `byte[] buf = {1, 1, 1, ...};` // e.g. 500 bytes. And update your question with the code of the test that you will actually run (I understand you already removed `BufferedOutputStream`)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to test your prog on Win XP, JDK 1.7.25.  Immediately got OutOfMemoryExceptions.

While debugging, with only 3000 count (args[1]), the count variable from this code:

```
    int count = 40 * 1024 * 1024 / content.length();
    int remainder = (40 * 1024 * 1024) % content.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        sb.append(content);
    }
```

count is 355449.  So the String you are trying to create will be 355449 * contents long, or as you calculated, 40Mb long.  I was out of memory when i was 266587, and sb was 31457266 chars long.  At which point each file I get is 30Mb.

The problem does not seem with memory or GC, but with the way you crate the string.

Did you see files created or was memory eating up before any file was created?

I think your main problem is the line:

```
  int count = 40 * 1024 * 1024 / content.length();
```

should be:

```
  int count = 40 * 1024 / content.length();
```

to create 40K, not 40Mb files.

Comment: I posted my program again. It will not use BufferedOutputStream, and it creates 40K file buffer just once.  It still created the same problem in Linux.  Would you please help me to solve the problem under Linux?

Comment: I do not have access to a Linux box now.  But I did not see any kind of memory leak when I profiled the app.  You may try to use the NetBeans Profiler?

Comment: @tttzhang2000 The updated version runs just fine for me under Linux using two different jvms.

Answer (score 0):

[**Edit2:** The original answer is left in *italics* at the end of this post]

After your clarifications in the comments, I have run your code on a windows machine (Java 1.6) and here is my findings (numbers are from VisualVM, OS memory as seen from task manager):

- Example with 40K size, writing to 500K files (no parameters to JVM):
  Used Heap: ~4M, Total Heap: 16M, OS memory: ~16M
- Example with 40M size, writing to 500 files (parameters to JVM -Xms128m -Xmx512m. Without parameters I get an OutOfMemory error when creating StringBuilder):
  Used Heap: ~265M, Heap size: ~365M, OS memory: ~365M

Especially from the second example you can see that my original explanation still stands. Yes someone would expect that most of the memory would be freed since the `byte[]` of the `BufferedOutputStream` reside in the first generation space (short lived objects) but this a) does not happen immediately and b) when GC decides to kicks in (it actually does in my case), yes it will try to clear memory but it can clear as much memory as it sees fit, not necessarily all of it. GC does not provide any guarentees that you can count upon.

So generally speaking you should give to JVM as much memory you feel comfortable with. If you need to keep the memory low for special functionalities you should try a strategy as the code example I gave down below in my original answer i.e. just don't create all those `byte[]` objects.

Now in your case with CentOS, it does seem that JVM's behaves strangely. Perhaps we could talk about a buggy or bad implementation. To classify it as a leak/bug though you should try to use `-Xmx` to restrict the heap. Also please try what [Peter Lawrey suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769962/does-outputstream-writebuf-offset-size-have-memory-leak#comment25918493_17769962)  to not create the `BufferedOutputStream` at all (in the small file case) since you just write all the bytes at once.

If it still exceeds the memory limit then you have encountered a leak and should probably file a bug. (You could still complain though and they may optimize it in the future).

---

*[Edit1: The answer below assumed that the OP's code performed as many reading operations as the write operations, so the memory usage was justifiable. The OP clarified this is not the case, so his question is not answered*

*"...my 15G memory VM..."
If you give the JVM as much memory why it should try to run GC? As far as the JVM is concerned it is allowed to get as much memory from the system and run GC only when it thinks that is appropriate to do so.
Each execution of `BufferedOutputStream` will allocate a buffer of 8K size by default. JVM will try to reclaim that memory only when it needs to. This is the expected behaviour.
Do not confuse the memory that you see as free from the system's point of view and from the JVM's point of view. As far the system is concerned the memory is allocated and will be released when the JVM shuts down. As far the JVM's is concerned all the `byte[]` arrays allocated from `BufferedOutputStream` are not in use any more, it is "free" memory and will be reclaimed if it needs to.
If for some reason you don't desire this behaviour you could try the following: Extend the `BufferedOutputStream` class (e.g. create a `ReusableBufferedOutputStream` class) and add a new method e.g. `reUseWithStream(OutputStream os)`. This method would then clear the internal `byte[]`, flush and close the previous stream, reset any variables used and set the new stream. Your code then would become as below:*

```
// intialize once
ReusableBufferedOutputStream fs = new ReusableBufferedOutputStream();
for (int i=0; i < fileCount; i ++)
{
    String path = String.format("%s%sTestFile_%d.txt", dir, File.separator, i);

    //set the new stream to be buffered and read
    fs.reUseWithStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
    fs.write(this._buf, 0, this._buf.length); // this._buf was allocated once, 40K long contain text
}
fs.close();  // Close the stream after we are done
```

*Using the above approach you will avoid creating many `byte[]`. However I don't see any problem with the expected behaviour neither you mention any problem other than "I see it takes too much memory". You have congifured it to use it after all.]*

Comment: I think most JVMs will collect a lot more frequently than that, even if they have free memory. It's a smart thing to think of, though. Explicitly invoking `Runtime.getRuntime().gc()` every hundred iterations or so would be a good thing to try.

Comment: @user2357112 not really. In the general case Java will behave as trying claim as much memory as it needs to, when it is under load (something is running). If all threads are doing nothing, eventually it will reclaim the memory. Calling `Runtime.getRuntime().gc()` is nothing more than a request. JVM can ignore it (and it usually does)

Comment: I could not believe an industrial strength language like java will behave like what is described here.  How can system not collect garbage and wait until it needs to.  It is very possible, when it finds that memory needs to be reclaimed, it is too late, because unclaimed memory eats up too much resource, and even OS has trouble to perform.  At the beginning I did add read operation after this, and because write operation eats all the memory, my read perform much slower than write, which is not normal for today's file system.  It would be a big flaw if java designed this way.

Comment: BTW, I tried explicitly call gc() every 100 files, it make no difference.  In C# code that transformed from this, I did nothing like forcing memory collection, and memory stabilized very quickly. If the memory issue I saw is due to java is so "lazy" in collecting memory garbage, I would be shocked!

Comment: I'd expect almost all of these objects to die in first-generation garbage collection, which I'm pretty sure runs a lot more often than "whenever the entire JVM's memory limit runs out".

Comment: In answering c.s's "answer", I didn't re-create byte[] buf, the buf was created just once.  And BufferedOutputStream just write the content of buf to the file.  If I recreated buf every time I write a file then it will be easy to explain the whole thing. But I didn't do that.  I just create byte[] buf once.  It should not create any memory leak.  It seems that BufferedOutputStream, the JDK component is leaking.  And it is the write() that's is leaking. When I commented out the code fs.write(), the memory stabilized!

Comment: @tttzhang2000 it seems that you are missing the point. It is not Java's fault. If you don't feel it should eat as much memory, lower the JVM's max memory using `–Xmx` when you start the JVM.

Comment: @tttzhang2000 I just saw your previous comment. Then my answer probably is not correct. Is it possible to post the whole code to run it in our machines?

Comment: @user2357112 I was under the impression that OP creates a buffer (that is allocated once) which was filled up continously by reading as many files from disk (I assumed that a BufferedInputStream was involved). This memory would probably not be in first-generation. But this no longer applies as the OP clarified that this is not the case.

Comment: I used -Xmx flag (as I explained in the updated question), and it take no effects.